# Get all media link of youtube without flashgot, youtube-dl or any tool

Tags: audio, video, youtube, download

When I open Youtube video, flashgot can get all link of media streamming, like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZELI.png

But when I find in youtube html source code, I only found some of that. Example I only found 1 link audio m4a(flashgot can get 3 quality low, medium and high). I tried find in http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=IDofVideo but found no more link.

So how can I get all video, audio link of youtube manual, without any automatic tool? Please help me, thanks very much

PS: My English not well so i wrote not good, I hope you understand, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found way to get all media link of Youtube, all it in manifest, manifest url is feild manifest when download video_info: youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=YoutubeVideoID